# Wcf Service and Xamarin PCL: data security

Tags: c#, wcf, security, xamarin

I write Wcf Service and the client on Xamarin.PCL (Android, iOS). How to ensure the highest security of data transmission between the client and Wcf Service? It is necessary to encrypt and sign the packets sended to Wcf Service and back. From the Wcf also requires authentication for User / Password. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no such thing as "highest" security. We all read about numerous successful attacks on most secure systems. It's all matter of how much efforts you want to invest in security. The only really highest security would be reached if you will not transmit data at all :-)

Having said that, you probably want some *reasonable* security level of data transmission. For this you probably should rely on some well-known solutions - SSL, for example. IMHO, ensuring that your application uses https protocol with valid certificate should be sufficient for most needs.

For Xamarin, I'd recommend to take a look on ModernHttpClient library. It's fast and have built-in certificate checks.